# Delphi deploy msvcr100.dll XE6

Tags: delphi, dll, indy, delphi-xe6

I'm using Indy with Delphi for FTP or email. With Delphi XE2 I deployed ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll and my application run correctly to my customers.

But since the upgrade to XE6, some clients have a error message who say that can not find msvcr100.dll.

Is it a new dll to deliver ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With your help, I found a solution.

With ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll delivered with XE6 I have need to deploy msvcr100.dll.
ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll are in Version 1.0.0.7 ( 1.0.0g in http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/ )

With the last release of it ( 1.0.1.10 ( 1.0.1j in http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/ ) I do not need to deploy msvcr100.dll .

Comment: Good. Of course, that's exactly what I said. Modulo the fact that I could not say anything about the versions of the OpenSSL DLLs that you were distributing because you didn't give us that information.

Answer (score 3):

`msvcr100.dll` is the MSVC 2010 runtime. Clearly your particular OpenSSL DLLs have a dependency on it. Many programs will install the MSVC runtime, so it's quite common to find some machines already have it, and others do not. That's what has happened here.

If you distribute the OpenSSL DLLs that you can get from the Fulgan site, then you won't need to distribute any further runtime. These DLLs don't have a dependency on the MSVC runtime. There's a link from the Indy page: http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/ssl.en.aspx

You should take a keen interest in the OpenSSL DLLs that you distribute because there are potential security issues. In recent times there have been some spectacular vulnerabilities found in the OpenSSL implementation that Indy relies upon.

Comment: Ok, so for you, there isn't difference of implementation between XE2 and XE6 ?

Comment: I don't understand that comment

Comment: My program built in XE2 without msvcr100.dll works fine to 700 customers. Since built in XE6 I have error with de msvcr100.dll.

Comment: Your question indicated that was because the Indy DLLs that you shipped had a dependency on msvcr100.dll. Is that not the case? Or does your program have extra dependencies that we don't know about?

Comment: I would suggest that first you use some dependancy scaner to check on which dynamic link libraries does your application depend. I would suggest using PE Explorer (http://www.heaventools.com/overview.htm) becouse its dependancy scaner is also able to list and show both direct dependancies of certain Executable and dependancies from other files that Executable directly depend on. It sorts and show them in a nice tree-like structure. So this should help you in finding out wheter msvcr100.dll is required by Indy (its own dll's) or by another component of your application.

Comment: Also note there are several versions of msvcr100.dll (all with the same file name), so even though you include it with your project, it might not be the right version, and then it will not be found.

Comment: It is just dependency with the indy into my programm (secure part). It's strange because in XE2 I never have to need to deploy msvcr100.dll, and if I understand, now I have to deploy msvcr100.dll into my "bin" folder program.

Comment: No. That's not what I said. Deploy OpenSSL DLLs that don't take a dependency on the MSVC runtime. You probably need to work out where you are getting these OpenSSL DLLs from. Particularly if you have been distributing old versions then your program may not have been as secure as you think.